# Android Zoom In Animation

Tags: android, zooming, pinchzoom

When i Zoom in on a PDF View with an animation i cannot zoom out with pinch zoom after, when I don't use the animation i can easily zoom in and zoom out with pinch zoom. I can't see the problem, is there some code that can simulate a pinch zoom to certain X and Y values?

My Zoom xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="3"
        android:toYScale="3"/>
</set>
```

Comment: show your java code

Comment: Its not important, I am using animations in the navigation graph `app:enterAnim="@anim/zoom_in"`

Answer (score 1):

write zoom_out.xml file like,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromXScale="1.0"
        android:fromYScale="1.0"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale=".2"
        android:toYScale=".2" />
</set>
```

and zoom_in.xml file such as,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:duration="600"
        android:fromXScale="2"
        android:fromYScale="2"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="4"
        android:toYScale="4" >
    </scale>
</set>
```

Comment: That just returns my view to its default values because it doesn't have the `android:fillAfter="true"` value. I want to keep it like that but also let me pinch zoom out of it..